# Best way to store stats of multiple people weekly

Tags: php, mysql, database, data-storage, data-management

I am using the Clash Of Clans api to show all the members of the clan on a web page. But now I want to save all the donations, cups and received donations on a weekly base. So i can see in a very clear overview who are the most active members. But the thing is. I just don't know how to design the database. I was thinking to create a table every week that would look like this: StatsWeek[number]: (MemberTag, Donations, DonationsReceived, Cups). But then at some point i will have a large amount of tables. So I tought there has to be a more efficient way. But I can't think of a better way.. I am using a MySql Database

Comment: Create one table with the week number as a field.

Comment: ...or something like that. You'll know when you hit on the right solution, because no further structural changes will be required to the database or its tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like mentioned in the comments, it's better to store everything in a single table... you can save weekly transactions(or daily, whatever interval you choose). [Here is an example schema for you.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4b7a60)

To find, for example, troops donated on any given week; you will have to subtract the previous weeks donations from that weeks donations.